# Does `std::shuffle` guarantees same order with same seed on different vectors?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, shuffle

I have two vectors with the same number of elements, but their types have completely different sizes. I need to shuffle them so that both have the exact same order after shuffling (each element in one vector is related each element in the other). The way I found to do it was:

```
// sizeof(a[0]) != sizeof(b[0])
// a.size() == b.size()
{
    std::mt19937 g(same_seed);
    std::shuffle(a.begin(), a.end(), g);
}
{
    std::mt19937 g(same_seed);
    std::shuffle(b.begin(), b.end(), g);
}
```

Can I rest assured that both vectors will be shuffled the same way? Is this implementation dependent? Do I have such guarantee from `std::shuffle` specification?

Comment: You'd probably be best off zipping them into a vector of pairs before doing the shuffle, or instead creating a new vector of indices, shuffling that, and using that to index into the parallel vectors.

Comment: My first attempt was the vector of indices, but my data is big and doesn't fit two copies in my memory, thus I tried loading it from disk in the shuffled order, what of course, was insanely slow. So I did this other way to be able to read from disk sequentially (very fast) and shuffle in place (no double memory).

Comment: The specification doesn't quite guarantee this although it is hard to imagine an implementation that wouldn't given the constraints the standard puts on shuffle.  The `suffle` algorithm itself is seems fairly simple to write so I would write my own implementation that would give me the guarantee. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Why use a pair of vectors instead of just a vector of pairs in the first place, then, if they're expected to remain parallel?

Comment: Because the external library I am using takes 2 separate vectors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an interesting statement about shuffle in the specification:

> Remarks: To the extent that the implementation of this function makes use of random numbers, the object `g` shall serve as the implementation’s source of randomness.

Even so, that statement doesn't help you. The "Remarks" section is normative text, so this is saying that `g` will provide the random numbers to determine the shuffled order. However, it does not declare that `g` is the only factor which determines the permutation.

While the size of the container's value probably doesn't matter, there's no *guarantee* that some property of the type wouldn't affect something. For example, if the value type were trivially copyable, an implementation might use a different version of the function that used a slightly different algorithm. However, if it were a register-sized value, it might not.

In short, no, `std::shuffle` does not guarantee what you're looking for.